# Trying to render 4 videos to my application from an api call to youtube

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
```

> **importing my hooks**

```
function useFetch(url, defaultResponse) {
    const [data, setData] = useState(defaultResponse);
    async function getDataFromAPI(url) {
        try {
            const res = await fetch(url);
            const data = await res.json();
            setData({
                isLoading: false,
                data
            })
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        getDataFromAPI(url);
    }, [url])
    return data;
}
```

> **Created a custom hook**

```
export default function YouTubeData() {
    const channelID = "UCXgGY0wkgOzynnHvSEVmE3A";
    const APIKEY = "my-working-key";
    const results = 4
    const apiEndpoint = `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=${APIKEY}&channelId=${channelID}&part=snippet,id&order=date&&maxResults=${results}`
    const userFetchResponse = useFetch(apiEndpoint, { isLoading: true, data: null });
    if (!userFetchResponse.data || userFetchResponse.isLoading) {
        return 'Loading...'
    }
```

> **When I console log userFetchResponse.data.items I get an object array with properties**

```
    const {videoId} = (userFetchResponse.data.items.map(obj => "http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + obj.id.videoId));

    return (
        <div>

            {
                videoId.map((link, i) => {
                    var frame =
                        <div key={i} className='youtube'>
                            <iframe
                                title={i}
                                width="560"
                                height="315"
                                src={link}
                                frameBorder="0"
                                allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
                                allowFullScreen>
                            </iframe>
                        </div>
                    return frame
                })
            }
            {this.frame}
        </div>
    )
}
```

> **I am trying to create a variable videoID to hold an array of the 4 URLs I will need for the jsx src but I keep getting an error of undefined can someone help?**

Comment: Please add more details about the error, which file, which line is it saying it's coming at?

Answer (score 0):

`const {videoId} = (userFetchResponse.data.items.map(obj => "http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + obj.id.videoId));`

The right hand side is an array using `map`, the left hand side has to be an array as well.

```
  const videoId = arr[0]
  // or
  const [videoId] = arr
```

But not `{videoId`, because that'll assume you have an object on the right hand side.

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```js
const {someVar} = something
```

Is the same as

```js
const someVar = something.someVar
```

In your case, you only want to store an array into a variable, so you just need

```
const videoIds = userFetchResponse.data.items.map(obj => "http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + obj.id.videoId);
```